# IOS Simulator crashes running iOS 13.0 devices

Tags: ios-simulator, macos-mojave, ios13, xcode11

IOS Simulator crashes running iOS 13.0 devices,

using XCode 11.0

Mojave 10.14.6 running as VM In VirtualBox 6.0.12

iOS 12.2 simulators run OK.

Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Repeating Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia and russbishop comments here.
Thanks them.

Had same issue and disabling AVX/AVX2 solved for me.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0
```

Other option, as mentioned russbishop, is to update VirptualBox to version supporting properly AVX.

Comment: Using Virutalbox and Catalina, still fixes the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please reference the actual log rather than an screenshot of the log.

Given that this is in the HEVC video code, I suspect your VM is advertising support for some CPU extensions that it doesn't actually support (eg: AVX).  If you attach to SpringBoard with lldb and check where it is crashing, that should tell you pretty quickly if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks, so potentially can enable AVX2 and retry (as AVX is on by default)

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe setextradata "osx-vm-name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 1

Comment: Some versions of VirtualBox incorrectly advertise support for AVX2 without actually supporting all of that instruction set, so when system frameworks attempt to use it they encounter SIGILL (illegal instruction) errors. Either disable it completely or update to a version that properly supports AVX2.

Answer (score 0):

Moved to VMWare, and no issues found, all good and faster.